# How to check if the first four characters of a column are 'http' or not?

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, numpy

I have a dataframe like:

```
df['Web']
```

I just want to check the first four characters of `df['Web']` is `'http'` or not.

I don't want to check if `df['Web']` is in url format or not.

And how to use if condition like :

```
if (firstfour=='http'):
   print("starts with http")
else:
   print("doesn't starts with http")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `string.startswith()`. However you should not that it would also match `https` as well.

You could use `regex` to match http and not https.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Web': ['htt', 'http', 'https', 'www']})
df['match'] = df.Web.apply(lambda x: x.startswith('http'))

     Web  match
0    htt  False
1   http   True
2  https   True
3    www  False
```

---

**Regex**

```
df['match'] = df['Web'].str.match(r'^http(?!s)')


     Web  match
0    htt  False
1   http   True
2  https  False
3    www  False
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`Series.str.startswith`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.startswith.html):

```
df['match'] = df.Web.str.startswith('http')
```

Or use [`Series.str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) with `^` for start of string:

```
df['match'] = df.Web.str.contains('^http')
```